# Gulp: running through all dependencies without duplicating?

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
gulp.task("compile-vendor-js", function() {
    return gulp.src("./bower_components/*/*.js")
        .pipe(concat("vendor.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./build"))
});
```

This gulp task will compile bower solved dependencies.

The problem is, it will consider all JS files, including the minified ones, making my build file have duplicated code.

I know that one solution for this is having a variable array containing all file paths, but this isn't good.

Comment: https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#usage-with-gulp

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
gulp.src(["./bower_components/*/*.js", "!./bower_components/*/*.min.js"])
```

where you can find a common denominator between all the minified js files (eg, .min.js)

I think that a blacklist of files is going to be shorter than a whitelist in this case.

Also, you might consider looking into the [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.org/package/main-bower-files) project, which will read your bower.json file and pull out the main js files from each project for you.